# How to convert a columnar list in Pandas to numpy matrix: expanding list to columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**Background:**

The actual problem I'm trying to solve is to go from a Spark Dataframe of SparseVectors to a numpy array. So as step 1 I decided to call a UDF on the desired column.

```
spark.udf.register("sparseToArray", lambda x: x.toArray().tolist(), ArrayType(elementType=FloatType(), containsNull=False))
```

and called it like so:

```
dense_input = input_df.selectExpr("sparseToArray(features) as features")
```

So now I could call toPandas() but I'd end up with a column of "list" objects which brings me to the topic of this post.

```
dense_input.toPandas()
# see below for how this shows up
```

**The Transformed Problem:**

I have a single column list of numbers from which I would like to create columns in `numpy`. I need help with that.

Pandas:

```
shape(3,1)
size = 3
Values: ndarray of lists

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 1 columns):
features    3 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 104.0+ bytes

Sample:

'features'
 0 list([1,2,3,4])
 1 list([5,6,7,8])
 2 list([9,10,11,12])
```

I would like to be ndarray like:

```
shape: [4,3]

[
 [1,2,3,4],
 [5,6,7,8],
 [9,10,11,12]
]
```

Comment: Storing lists in dataframes is not recommended. Still, `ar = features.values.tolist()`

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. How do you end up with a Dataframe of lists?

Comment: added some comments to give some background

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT: This should be what you want then.**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame()
data['Feature'] = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]

def iterator(dataframe_column):
    for i in dataframe_column:
        yield i
matrix = []
for row in iterator(data['Feature']):
    matrix.append(row)

result = np.array(matrix)
>>> print(result.shape)
(3, 4)

>>> result
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])

>>> type(result)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

If the problem still persist, you need to provide code. I cant reproduce list objects in dataframe except those in my code

Comment: Isn't that the same as ".values"? It doesn't do what i want

Comment: Check my edit. You have wrong shape. You need shape (3,4)

Answer (score -1):

as said in the comment, you could use

```
my_array = np.array(df.features.values.tolist())

my_array
Out[56]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
type(my_array)
Out[57]: numpy.ndarray
```

storing object in dataframe is not recommanded and can lead to unexpected behavior

Comment: Somehow I end up with an array of list objects